# Sort list of Strings by another list containing substrings of original

Tags: java, list, sorting

I've tried every other question and answer on SO regarding this topic, but I haven't managed to make it work.

I have a list of specifically ordered strings for example: `["serviceT", "servicC", "serviceA", ... "serviceZ"]`.

I have another list of complete paths to jar files of the same name:
`["C:\Users\USER\projects .... \serviceB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" ...]`. This list is completely unordered. This list is generated using this:

```
servicesPaths = Files.walk(Paths.get(parentFolder))
    .map(Path::toString)
    .filter(path -> {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (String service : services)
            if (path.endsWith(version + ".jar") && path.contains(service)) flag = true;
            return flag;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Essentially I just give it a parent folder, and it returns a list of all paths that contain `service`. Both lists end up the same size. I mean, each `service` has exactly one `path`.

I need to order the `servicePath` list, so that it will be the same order as the `services` ordered list.

I've tried using every method of sorting / comparator I could think of, and could only make it work using a very brute for loop:

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (String service : services)
    for (String path : servicesPaths)
        if (path.indexOf(service) > 0)
            temp.add(path);
```

Is there any other sensible way to sort the `servicePaths` list ?

Comment: Be precise about your terminology: don't call a list that is not sorted sorted. Call it a list with defined order of elements or such. But the term sorted leads to all kinds of wrong expectations.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @Bugs I didn't come up with the solution. Nestor Sokil's answer is the correct one, which is why I marked his answer as accepted. I only edited the question with the exact code for clarity. All I did was refactor it a bit.

Comment: @maydawn OK that's fine but I would refrain from adding in "working" solutions into your question. Question = problem, answer = solution. This is just to try and avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really straight-forward solution, but I think it's appropriate:

```
List<String> services = Arrays.asList("serviceA", "serviceC", "serviceB");
List<String> servicesPaths = Arrays.asList("serviceA-bla-bla", "serviceB-bla-bla", "serviceC-bla-bla");
List<String> sortedServices = servicesPaths.stream()
            .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(
                    services.indexOf(a.substring(0, a.indexOf("-"))), 
                    services.indexOf(b.substring(0, b.indexOf("-")))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The substring part is just extracting the service name from path. If you have any other ways to do it, just replace it with smth else.

Also, I would improve this snippet by storing the comparing func in a variable:

```
Function<String, Integer> indexInServices = path -> services.indexOf(path.substring(0, path.indexOf("-")));
List<String> orderedServices = servicesPaths.stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(indexInServices))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `new Integer(a).compareTo(b)` = `Integer.compare(a, b)`.

Answer (score 1):

The first optimization: as both lists have equal size you can **remove** the paths after adding them. That reduces the number of inner loops for each run of the outer loop.

But what I would do: change the way how you **generate** that path list. You see: first of all you have another N * N there already. And then another N * N later one?!

Instead:

- put your services into a `Map<String, Integer>`: key is the string, value the **index** in the service list
- create an **empty** list for the paths - that has service **empty** slots!
- then, when you process the file paths, simply check for each Map key if it "matches" - and on a match ... you just look into that map and you know the position that this path should have. So you can simply insert it into that list you prepared in step 2!

Should be enough to get you going - I guess you will have to carefully look into constraints such as "sizes of lists really identical" and so on (if you have less paths than services, that intermediate list might contain some empty slots which you would have to remove then).

Answer (score 1):

Sort `servicesPaths` by the substring that follows the string "`Service`"

Let *m* be the size of `servicesPath`
Let *n* be the size of your sorted Strings.

Then use the pseudocode

`for each string in servicesPath
   search SortedStrings by binary search`

This solution is time *O(m* log (n) )*
since binary search is order *O(log n)*

Your brute force solution is time *O(m * n)*

Should the size  of sorted paths be smaller than the size of sorted strings
create an array of records.  (Note, that is not the situation poster has.)

```
class Pair {
     String str;
     int pos;
   }
   Pair []Pairs;
   Pairs = new Pair[sorted strings.length];
```

for each item in the sorted Strings, copy the string to `Pair[i]s.str` and
its ordinal position to `Pairs[i].pos`

Then, sort `Pairs` by `str`, using the straightforward comparator

Then for each item in `servicesPaths`, you take the string and do a binary
in `Pairs` for it.  When you find the one that matches, call its position `pos`.
Copy that item of `servicesPaths` into `path[pos]`
.

This is a great exercise for a CS2 (datastructures) class.

Answer (score 0):

Every item in the list you call "sorted" (but which really is just ordered according to some opaque criteria) has a position or index within the list.

THAT position/index is the key to use in sorting the other list.

For each element in the list to be sorted, look it up in the "ordered" list and apply the found element's index as the sort key.

Answer (score 0):

You probably realize that you need to sort based on `services` index. Here another way to do what you need:

```
    public static class ServicePath{
        private Integer index = 0;
        private String path = null;

        public ServicePath(Integer index, String path){
            this.index = index;
            this.path = path;
        }

        public Integer getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public void setIndex(Integer index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setPath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }
    }


    List<ServicePath> servicesPaths = Files.walk(Paths.get(parentFolder))
    .map(Path::toString)
    .map( path -> {                
            for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) if ( path.endsWith(version + ".jar" ) && path.contains( services.get(i) ) ) return new ServicePath(i, path);
            return null;                    
    })
    .filter( sp -> sp != null)        
    .collect( Collectors.toList() );

    servicesPaths.sort( (sp1, sp2) -> sp1.getIndex().compareTo( sp2.getIndex() ) );

    List<String> sortedPaths = servicesPaths.stream().map( sp -> sp.getPath() ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```